# How to find all the events of a control in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in android development. I installed android studio in my pc. Now when I add a control in my activity I didn't find any event of that control or may be I don't know the exact location of all the events due to lack of knowledge in android studio.

I am a Asp.net developer and when I add any control in  my page there is seperate place for all the events of that control. Let's say When I add DropDownList in my page I can View all the events such as OnClick, OnSelectedIndexChanged, OnLoad, OnTextChanged etc. And If I want to code inside any particular event I simple double click on that event and Visual Studio let me go to the exact event on Code Behind (C#).

But In android studio I am unable to find any seperate place for all the events of any particular control like visual studio. If I have to add a spinner and code anything inside **OnItemSelected** event I have to write it in Java class (i.e. MainActivity.java).

Please suggest me the right way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android logic is different from c # (WPF or WF)
You need to specify the element id in xml  file.

`<Button
            android:id="@+id/your_button_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text" />`

Then find it in Activity and set listener

```
Button myButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_name);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
```

If you want to see all listener you can put `.` after `myButton` and see all available methods

Comment: This is the only way to view all the listeners of a control ?
Can't I see all the listners in design view like properties of a control ?

Comment: I think it's impossible. One layout can be used in different places. And use a variety of listeners to their elements